# How to add constraint in my UISegmentedControl inside UIToolbar

Tags: ios

Is there a way to add constraints here? What I've tried so far is to add FlexibleSpace and FixedSpace but it doesn't stretch out my Segmented Control? How can I stretch it depending on the screen size?

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide about the left and right margin this segment control can have for different screen size. If you wish to keep is constant lets say, 20 pixels for all screen size, then you can add `Leading` and `Trailing` edge constraints to it. Do not keep any constraints on the width of segment control.